# How do I create a Vec of Entries from a HashMap?

Tags: types, rust

Given a `HashMap<Token, Frequency>`, I want a `Vec` of references to these pairs. I found that the pairs are of type `Entry`, so it would look something like:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

type Freq = u32;
type Token = String;

struct TokenizeState {
    tokens: HashMap<Token, Freq>,
    text: Vec<std::collections::hash_map::Entry<Token, Freq>>,
}

fn main() {}
```

This code has an error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:8:15
  |
8 |     text: Vec<std::collections::hash_map::Entry<Token, Freq>>,
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Adding a lifetime specifier to the struct leads to the same error:

```
struct TokenizeState<'a> {
    tokens: HashMap<Token, Freq>,
    text: Vec<&'a std::collections::hash_map::Entry<Token, Freq>>,
}
```

My main problem is that I don't know if `std::collections::hash_map::Entry<Token, Freq>` is the correct type. I have experimented with a lot things, like the more obvious `HashMap<Token, Freq>::Entry`, and couldn't get it work.

Comment: I don't think it will work to use `Entry` in this way, because `Entry` is intended for modifying the map. This means that it encapsulates a mutable borrow, and you can only have one entry at a time. So you should probably define your own type for pairing keys and values (or just use pairs).

Comment: @Shepmaster actually, I've used more general `a map of` instead of `a HashMap<Token, Frequency>` on purpose. Like, I'm okay with any alike type, and even rather likely would go with BTreeMap IRL *(well, if it worked anyway as noted starblue in comment above)*. Also, why you replaced `test.rs` with `src/main.rs`? And why you changed title from `Create…` to `How do I create…` with question mark at the end? The first one is shorter, and doesn't make the question any less clear.

Comment: *more general* — this question doesn't make sense to be general. An arbitrary map type may not have a corresponding `Entry`, or its `Entry` may not have a lifetime parameter, etc. *src/main.rs* — I copied your code into the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to format it, ensure it compiles, and ensure the error message matches the code (**many** questions do not). The playground uses `main.rs` as its filename; there's no meaningful difference. *changed title* — Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. Questions have question marks and are complete English sentences.

Comment: @Shepmaster *Questions have question marks and are complete English sentences* — not necessarily, exactly because it's a Q&A site. E.g. if you send a patch that `fixes #123`, you don't write `When applied, it fixes #123`, it's unnecessarily because it's obvious. Same here: in `I'm asking, how to create a Vec of Entries` there's redundant text, it's a question by virtue of the site being Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime is needed on `Entry`, as you can see in [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html). Like this:

```
struct TokenizeState<'a> {
    tokens: HashMap<Token, Freq>,
    text: Vec<std::collections::hash_map::Entry<'a, Token, Freq>>,
}
```